# Calculating a net spatial rate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have calculated a net 'rate', based on the sum of 3 separate, related rates.  I need to use this rate as a weight in another equation.  However, in some cases, the net rate is negative (which is expected).  Since the rate is in 'cases', a negative number simply means that a given area is contributing cases at a slower rate than other areas (there is a net decrease in cases from the area).

The equation I'm using it in, however, was designed to work with positive values.  Is there a way to transform my values into positive values?  Or, does it make a difference?  i.e. if I apply a rate that has both negative and positive values to an equation that expects only positive values, do I have to do something different to account for the negative values?

Thanks.

Jess

Comment: Your question seems too vague. Could you give more précisions about the context?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be more precise.  From above, I have three different types of 'people' in a set of locations who have traveled varying distances to purchase -

1. People who buy,
2. People who could buy, but don't,
3. & the remaining population in that location.

You can use these types to asses how geographic behavior affects the rates.  To to this, the equation is:

1 + (3 - 2)

So, purchasing behavior plus the spatial 'risk' to the remaining population.  The equation works really well, and in areas where we know there is low risk for purchas, the value is negative, which can only happen if 2 is greater than both 1 & 3.

Normally, I take this cumulative value and plug it into a form to calculate the rate 'above average'.  That's a simple weighted percent equation in which the purchasers in location i are weighted by the cumulative value and divided by the total diagnosed cases.  This method is then repeated for expected purchases (developed using proprietary rates).  So, the expected cases are weighted by the same cumulative value, which is akin to saying 'if expected cases were subjected to the same spatial environment as the real cases, how many would we see?'.

You then subtract the weighted expected rate from the weighted real rate to get the value above or below average.  If you then multiply that value by the total expected value, it gives you the equivalent number of cases expressed as a function of the proprietary values, which can then be compared to other locations.

Here's the problem: does the negative cumulative rate need to be altered such that is expressed in positive terms?   If you subtract a negative from a negative, and the second negative is smaller than the first, it yields a positive value.  If that were to happen and both values were positive, you'd also yield a positive.  But, given that the second value is smaller in the case I've presented, it is illogical to say 'there are cases above average' in that location.